# Why does this golang pointer address not change when replaced in goroutine?

Tags: pointers, go

It's my understanding that when I create an object with the `foo := &bar{}` I'm allocating new memory for that object. Why then, when I attempt to replace *foo in a goroutine does it not get a new pointer address?

```golang
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "math/rand"
    "sync"
    "time"
)

type pointerToObjects struct {
    objs *objects
}
type objects struct {
    sliceOfObject []*object
}
type object struct {
    number  int
    boolean bool
}

func main() {
    p := &pointerToObjects{objs: newObjects()}
    mu := &sync.Mutex{}

    for _, o := range p.objs.sliceOfObject {
        o.setBool(true)
    }
    // goroutine 1
    go func() {
        ticker := time.NewTicker(time.Second)
        defer ticker.Stop()
        for range ticker.C {
            mu.Lock()
            fmt.Printf("objects pointer: %v\n", &p.objs)
            for i, o := range p.objs.sliceOfObject {
                fmt.Printf("i: %d p: %v n: %d b: %t\n", i, &o, o.number, o.boolean)
            }
            fmt.Print("---\n")
            mu.Unlock()
        }
    }()
    // goroutine 2
    go func() {
        ticker := time.NewTicker(time.Second * 2)
        defer ticker.Stop()
        for range ticker.C {
            newObjects := &objects{sliceOfObject: newSliceOfObject()}
            mu.Lock()
            p.objs = newObjects
            mu.Unlock()
            fmt.Printf("replaced: %v <-- %v \n", &p.objs, &newObjects)
        }
    }()

    // let the goroutines run for 10 seconds
    time.Sleep(time.Second * 10)
}
func newObjects() *objects {
    objs := &objects{}
    objs.sliceOfObject = newSliceOfObject()
    return objs
}

func newSliceOfObject() []*object {
    var sliceObjs []*object
    for i := 0; i < 3; i++ {
        sliceObjs = append(sliceObjs, newObject())
    }
    return sliceObjs
}
func newObject() *object {
    return &object{number: rand.Int()}
}

func (obj *object) setBool(b bool) {
    obj.boolean = b
}
```

[playground link](https://play.golang.org/p/nPhOUqNjuVY)

actual:

```
objects pointer: 0xc00000e030
i: 0 p: 0xc00009a010 n: 5577006791947779410 b: true
i: 1 p: 0xc00009a010 n: 8674665223082153551 b: true
i: 2 p: 0xc00009a010 n: 6129484611666145821 b: true
---
replaced: 0xc00000e030 <-- 0xc00000e040 
objects pointer: 0xc00000e030
i: 0 p: 0xc00000e050 n: 4037200794235010051 b: false
i: 1 p: 0xc00000e050 n: 3916589616287113937 b: false
i: 2 p: 0xc00000e050 n: 6334824724549167320 b: false
```

expected:

```
objects pointer: 0xc00000e030
i: 0 p: 0xc00009a010 n: 5577006791947779410 b: true
i: 1 p: 0xc00009a010 n: 8674665223082153551 b: true
i: 2 p: 0xc00009a010 n: 6129484611666145821 b: true
---
replaced: 0xc00000e030 <-- 0xc00000e040 
objects pointer: 0xc00000e040
i: 0 p: 0xc00000e050 n: 4037200794235010051 b: false
i: 1 p: 0xc00000e050 n: 3916589616287113937 b: false
i: 2 p: 0xc00000e050 n: 6334824724549167320 b: false
```

when run, the values update as I would expect, but the pointer in `p` to `objects` remains unchanged. I would expect it to be updated when I call `*p.objs = *newObjects`

is this a trick of the compiler? How can I get "objects pointer" to update to the new location? do I need to use more explicit pointers to pointers?

EDIT: fixed race condition and tried to assigned with `p.objs = newObjects` without success.

Comment: The program has a data race.  Run [race detector](https://golang.org/doc/articles/race_detector.html) and fix the reported problems.

Comment: @CeriseLimón there is a race, but it doesn't affect the outcome. I fixed it here: https://play.golang.org/p/r4skf6C6ISS and the results are unchanged.

Comment: The program prints the address of local variable `o`. I think you want to print the value of `o`.

Comment: `*p.objs = *newObjects` changes the value pointed by `p.objs`. Why would this change the address of `p.objs`?

Comment: @icza 'p.objs = newObjects` has the same result though. this is where I started and should have mentioned. thank you!
@CeriseLimón o is an object in a slice of objects. it's pointer value is updating as expected. it's the parent object that I can't seem to change.

Comment: Similar to the issue with `o`: The program prints `&p.objs`. This value does not change in the program. I think you want to print `p.objs` instead.. https://play.golang.org/p/3KyTLyXyouP

Comment: @CeriseLimón I think you're right. I didn't realize that printing p.objs with %p would be different than &p.objs. why are they different?

Comment: The important change is replacing `&p.objs` with `p.objs` in the print calls. Printing the address of the field is different from printing the value of the field. The change from `%v` to `%p` ensures that the value is printed as a pointer.  https://play.golang.org/p/7b7vL_BzhdS

Comment: please feel free to answer, you nailed it.

Comment: @AaronSmall - a side note, you said "there is a race, but it doesn't affect the outcome", and provide as "evidence" the fact that after you fixed it the result was unchanged. Well, that's not really how it works. A data race, by definition, makes the program's behavior *undefined*. It may result in what "you'd expect"; but in the presence of a data race, the compiler doesn't guarantee anything about the result. Check this article (not go, but same thing): https://software.intel.com/content/www/us/en/develop/blogs/benign-data-races-what-could-possibly-go-wrong.html

Comment: @BrunoReis - Thanks for contributing. in general, I'd agree. in this specific example though, the goroutines are designed to be twiddling the same bits and one runs 2x as often as the other. the faster one would run between one and two times between each slower loop. obviously data races are important in actual software, I was just saying that in this example it's a red herring.

Comment: @AaronSmall Fix known data races before asking a question in case the data race is responsible for the unexpected results.  It was a typo in this question, but the typo was  not as easy to spot as the data race (at least for me).

Comment: @CeriseLimón good point. thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the exception of the printed output, the program works as you expect.

To print the value of a variable, use the variable in the fmt.Printf argument list. Do not pass the address of the variable.  The value of a variable and the address of a variable are different things.

To best view pointers, print pointers with the `%p` verb instead of `%v`.

Here's one example. Change

```
        fmt.Printf("replaced: %v <-- %v \n", &p.objs, &newObjects)
```

to

```
        fmt.Printf("replaced: %p <-- %p \n", p.objs, newObjects)
```

The issue unrelated to the use of goroutines as mentioned in the title.